# Computing a FFT on CSV Data

Tags: python, fft

i would like to get the FFT out of my CSV Data to analyse it afterwards. Im very new in Programming.
This is a look in my CSV Data:

Zeit;Kanal A;Kanal B;Kanal C;Kanal D

(s);(mV);(mV);(mV);(V)

0;2,734709;-13,00818;10,01709;-10,22464
0,0001;2,618728;-12,8922;9,547064;-10,22464
0,0002;0,3845684;-16,54865;2,862898;-4,42559
0,0003;3,082652;-11,47601;12,36113;-4,42559
0,0004;2,496643;-13,00818;9,431083;-4,42559
0,0005;2,496643;-12,77622;9,663045;-7,32511
0,0006;2,966671;-13,48431;18,3372;-13,12416
0,0007;0,9705775;-14,9005;6,14699;-16,02368
0,0008;2,496643;-12,06812;11,65303;-18,92321
0,0009;1,794653;-12,8922;10,13307;-16,02368
0,001;2,026615;-12,8922;10,36504;-16,02368
0,0011;4,492736;-6,995483;17,75119;-10,22464
0,0012;1,208644;-13,71627;8,13698;-7,32511
0,0013;1,794653;-12,77622;11,42107;-4,42559

The total length of my CSV Data is ~100.000 rows.

```
from os import sep
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from pathlib import Path
from numpy.fft import rfft, rfftfreq,irfft




dt=1/10000

g=pd.read_csv('20210803-0002.csv', sep = ';', skiprows=[1,2],usecols = [4],dtype=float, decimal=',')
    

n=len(g)
   
acc=g.values.flatten()
    
fft=abs(rfft(acc)*dt)
freq=rfftfreq(n,d=dt)

FFT=abs(fft)

plt.plot(freq,FFT)
plt.show()
```

Does this code makes sense to compute and plot a FFT with it ?

I got this problem:

[image]

I expect a peak at 15, but it is at 14.75

I am happy for every useful feedback !

Comment: Don't multiply the fft with dt. I'm not sure why you do that. You also use abs() twice. Once is enough ;) 
Further, it is fine to use the fft like this, but remember that you are throwing away half of your information when you only use the magnitude. You are throwing away the phase. This is not inherently an issue, but it should be kept in mind. 
Ultimately it depends what your aim is. But perhaps you will want to have a look at periodogramms.

Comment: My x axis values are 0.25 units shifted. I think thats a problem with my sampling rate. Do you know how to remedie this ?

Comment: I add a picture to show my problem :)

Comment: did you verify the data came from the csv properly? skipsrows is 0 indexed. not 1. The read may have skipped some data

Comment: yes, i got the data properly